# How to remove list of figures from table of contents in book document class

Tags: table-of-contents

How to remove list of figures from table of contents ?
Here's M. W. E of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Really appreciate if anyone can answer. Thanks in advance!

PS:
This is my first post. So excuse if I haven't asked this in the required format. I found some posts which had asked a similar question. But still I couldn't resolve mine

Comment: +1 for a MINIMAL working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `notlof` option to `tocbibind`, and also the `notlot` option if you don't want the LoT title added to the ToC.

```
\usepackage{nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
```

Reaf the manual for more information (`> texdoc tocbibind`).

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked

Comment: I think it should be '[' instead of '{'.

```\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}```